# To limit the size of the options shown in the drop down and making the rest scrollable in angular4

Tags: angular

```
 <select [ngClass]="{'invalid-class': (!territory.valid && !territory.pristine 
  &&  serviceName.valid)}" class="form-control" 
  (change)="fetctLoS(serviceObject.territory)"
   [(ngModel)]="serviceObject.territory" name="territory" 
   #territory="ngModel" [disabled]="!serviceName.valid">
         <option [value]="" class="deafaultOption"></option>
         <option [ngValue]="item"  *ngFor="let item of territoryList"> . 
         {{item.territory_name}}</option>
  </select>
```

How can I limit the number of options(eg:10) in my select and making rest of them as scrollable

Comment: you probably need to create a custom control; you cannot achieve this with just `select`. Do you have UI for the end state of the select box that you can share?

Comment: @akhouri thanks I'll try to share but its normal select drop down only, any help would be appreciated

Comment: @akhouri I can give you a link https://www.google.co.in/search?q=select+dropdown+images&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio1pXb_sDaAhWJpI8KHR7ACwMQ_AUICigB&biw=1352&bih=700&dpr=2&safe=active&ssui=on#imgrc=TBvokMs_sAHetM:

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, here's my solution (created a custom control):
Hope this gives you one of the choices you could go for.

**Custom component** - `scrollable-select`

**Usage**: `<scrollable-select [showSelect]="showSelect" [unscrollableOptions]="unscrollableOptions" [scrollableOptions]="scrollableOptions" (selectedMenu)="handleSeletedMenu($event)"></scrollable-select>`

**Component's UI**
[image]

**Demo**
[Link](https://angular-scrollable-select.stackblitz.io)

**Code**
[Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scrollable-select)

Let me know if this approach was helpful.